# How to pre fill fields in an angularjs form?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Guacamole (Web RDP client developped with angularjs) and I would like to pre fill the login field.

I tryed many things today without any success.

This is the HTML code:

```
<html ng-app="index" ng-controller="indexController">
<head>...</head>
<body ng-class="page.bodyClassName">

    <!-- Content for logged-in users -->
    <div ng-if="!expectedCredentials">...</div>

    <!-- Login screen for logged-out users -->
    <guac-login ng-show="expectedCredentials"
                help-text="loginHelpText"
                form="expectedCredentials"
                values="acceptedCredentials"></guac-login>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

If I well understood, the  form send the datas $scope.enteredValues to the JS code. But I don't arrive to pre set this datas {username, password}.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to give values to the members of `acceptedCredentials` when loading the form.

Comment: OK but how ? I am a JS noob :-)

Comment: Show your controller code, where you create `$scope.acceptedCredentials`.

Comment: I replace the null by {username: 'test'} and it does not work anymore